# Python: comparing two synonyms through a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of synonyms:

```
synonym = {"this": ["this", "same"],
           "all": ["all", "any", "*"],
           "alluptolastyear": ["alluptolastyear", "uptolastyear"],
           "dekadbefore": ["dekadbefore", "lastdekad", "formerdekad", "precedingdekad"],
           "dekadafter": ["dekadafter", "nextdekad", "followingdekad"],
           "yearbefore": ["yearbefore", "lastyear", "formeryear"],
           "monthbefore": ["monthbefore", "lastmonth", "precedingmonth"]}
```

Each array stores synonyms, referenced through the keys.
I read two strings from an XML file, and try to compare them.

For example:

- `"this"` and `"same"` are equal (synonyms)
- '"lastyear"' and '"formeryear"' are equal (synonyms)
- `"all"` and `"nextdekad"` are different
- of course, each key value is found in its corresponding array, so each key is a synonym of its array's strings.

Could some help me to write a pythonic comparison of those strings using the synonym dictionary?

Comment: In your example, is `lastyear` a synonym for `formeryear`?

Comment: Yes, it is. All values inside an array are synonyms, they are referenced through the dictionary key.

Comment: could you please provide the code using which one can generate the synonym dictionary you sow here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
def are_sinonims(a, b):
    return a in synonym.get(b,[]) or b in synonym.get(a,[]) or any(a in synonym[k] and b in synonym[k] for k in synonym)
```

Also, we can rewrite the part `a in synonym[k] and b in synonym[k] for k in synonym` to `a in words and b in words for words in synonym.values()` such that:

```
def are_sinonims(a, b):
    return a in synonym.get(b,[]) \
           or b in synonym.get(a,[]) \
           or any(a in words and b in words for words in synonym.values())
```

Comment: How about `a in words and b in words for words in synonym.values()`?

Answer (score 4):

You can convert each word into "synonyms hash" (something that is equal if two words are synonyms and different otherwise):

```
def sym_hash(word):
    for w, s in synonym.items():
        if word == w or word in s:
            return w
    return word
```

And then compare words using their "hashes":

```
def phrases_equal(p1, p2):
    return all(sym_hash(a) == sym_hash(b) for a, b in zip(p1, p2))

p1 = "all your base this dekadbefore are formeryear".split()
p2 = "any your base same lastdekad are yearbefore".split()

print phrases_equal(p1, p2) # True
```

Actually, the proper data structure for the synonyms database appears to be a list of sets, not a dict:

```
synonym = [
    {"this", "same"},
    {"all", "any", "*"},
    {"alluptolastyear", "uptolastyear"},
    {"dekadbefore", "lastdekad", "formerdekad", "precedingdekad"},
    {"dekadafter", "nextdekad", "followingdekad"},
    {"yearbefore", "lastyear", "formeryear"},
    {"monthbefore", "lastmonth", "precedingmonth"}
]
```

in which case we can code `sym_hash` more efficiently as

```
def sym_hash(word):
    return next((s for s in synonym if word in s), word)
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
def are_sinonims(a, b):
    return b in synonym.get(a, []) or a in synonym.get(b, [])
```

Edited after comment with fault.

Comment: will not work correctly if a=="lastmonth" and b=="precedingmonth"

Comment: this solution doesn't work for `"formeryear"` and `"last year"`

Comment: but are we sure that's what we want ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make new dict for every synonyms as a key:

```
word_to_word = {}    
for syns in synonym.values():
    for word in syns:
        word_to_word[word] = syns
```

Function compare strings:

```
def are_sinomic(a, b):    
    words_a, words_b = a.split(), b.split()
    if len(words_a) != len(words_b):
        return False
    for word_a, word_b in zip(words_a, words_b):
       if word_a != word_b and word_b not in word_to_word.get(word_a, []):
           return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned that something **is** a synonym, then you can just build a set of 2-tuples from the permutations of the dict's values...:

```
synonym = {"this": ["this", "same"], 
           "all": ["all", "any", "*"], 
           "alluptolastyear": ["alluptolastyear", "uptolastyear"], 
           "dekadbefore": ["dekadbefore", "lastdekad", "formerdekad", "precedingdekad"], 
           "dekadafter": ["dekadafter", "nextdekad", "followingdekad"], 
           "yearbefore": ["yearbefore", "lastyear", "formeryear"], 
           "monthbefore": ["monthbefore", "lastmonth", "precedingmonth"]} 

from itertools import chain, permutations
synonym_set = set(chain.from_iterable(permutations(val, 2) for val in synonym.values()))

def are_synonyms(a, b):
    return (a, b) in synonym_set
```